# How to match multiple different cases in Python

Tags: python, switch-statement, pattern-matching, python-3.10

Using the `match` statement, one can specify multiple patterns for the same case\

```py
match value:
   case 1 | 2 | 3:
     do_a()
   case 4:
     do(b)
```

What I want to do is the inverse, I want to match multiple cases, each of which executes a different code, with a single value - my idea was something like this

```py
match value:
   case 1 | 2 | 3 | 'all':
     do_a()
   case 4 | 'all':
     do(b)
   case 'all':
     do(c)
```

I want to run both `do_a()`, `do_b()` and `do_c()` if `value=='all'`. This can be easily done with `if-else`, but I wanted to make use of the more elegant `match` statement. In other languages with `switch`, like Java or C, I could abuse the need for explicit `break` and let the subsequent cases be executed after the first match.

Is there a mechanism for this use-case in either fashion (executing multiple blocks with matching the same value or 'falling through' the statement) in python, or do I have to settle down for simple conditions?

Currently the working version is with simple `if` conditions, I've tried the naive approach described in the problem, but only the first match block executes.

Comment: I think this is not possible by design: *"However, once the first matching pattern is found, the body of that case is executed, and all further cases are ignored. This is similar to the way that an if/elif/elif/... statement works."* (https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#matching-multiple-patterns)

Comment: You could of course have 3 `match` statements (each with 1 `case`) if you prefer that stylistically to `if` statements.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the best you can do is:

```
match value:
   case 'all':
     do_a()
     do(b)
     do(c)
   case 1 | 2 | 3:
     do_a()
   case 4:
     do(b)
```

Note the order.